# PHP insert multiples campos a base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Una duda al momento de ingresar un comentarios a un trabajador a la base de datos mediante su ID solo me ingresa un solo comentario no los múltiples que les puedo agregar mediante los textbox.

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });    
 });  
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <input type="text" name="id" value="01">
                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  

                                         <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                    </tr> 
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  

           <?php 

  include 'include/conexion.php';
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $number = count($_POST["name"]); 
 if($number > 0)  
 {  

      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
      {  

           if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))  
           {  

                $sql = "INSERT INTO observacion (id,motivo) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id'][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";  
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  

           }  
      }  
      ?> 
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <strong>Observacion Ingresada!</strong> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo "Please Enter Name";  
 } 
 }


  ?>
```

Comment: Hola MoteCL. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tu pregunta no está clara, por favor explica mejor lo que intentas conseguir y ejemplos de los datos que introduces . Para más informacion mira[ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Veo que el `$number = count($_POST["name"]);` devuelve bien la longitud del array. La base de datos tiene `id` cómo primary key? Es posible que sólo te deje introducir un registro por ello.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero si la query la edito y solo agrego el campo de motivo para ingresa funciona bien.
El problema seria al agregar el ID no funciona como debería solo agrega un motivo con la ID

Comment: Es posible que el id sea único en la base de datos? Y sólo te deje introducir 1 registro.

Comment: la tabla observación esta relaciona con la  tabla trabajador_id foreign key. Si ingreso un motivo de a uno sirve pero deseo ingresar múltiples motivos a la vez

Comment: ¿Cual es la estructura de la tabla `observacion`? Si `id` es la columna que se auto-incrementa, y una columna de esa misma tabla llamada `trabajador_id` es llave foránea con respecto a la tabla `trabajador`, entonces tu consulta de inserción debería ser: `INSERT INTO observacion (trabajador_id,motivo) VALUES(...)` . Aún así, deberías controlar los duplicados en la tabla `observacion`. Habría sido muy útil para una posible respuesta que indicases la estructura de las tablas y cómo se relacionan entre sí.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `bd`.`observacion` ( `observacion_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `id` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL , `motivo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`observacion_id`), FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES trabajador(id)ON DELETE CASCADE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo encontramos en esta línea:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO observacion (id,motivo)
    VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id'][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";
```

En concreto en `$_POST['id'][$i]`, el `id` desde el formulario no se está enviando como Array si no como una variable más.

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="01">
```

El forma de solucionarlo es simple

Bien llamamos a  `$_POST['id']` tal cual sin el `[$i]` ya que parece que es el mismo `id` para todos los comentarios.

O bien indicamos que es un `Array` en el form con los corchetes  `[ ]`.

```
<input type="text" name="id[]" value="01">
```

Para este caso concreto sería recomendable utilizar sentencias preparadas ya que nos permiten ejecutar la misma sentencia iterando solo los valores, de forma rápida. Aparte de simplificar el código y facilitar la prevención de la inyección SQL.

---

Ejemplo de código con sentencias preparadas, también corregí algunos errores que vi.

### form

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Este input deberia estar dentro del form -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="id" value="01"> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- En el form falta el action y el method -->
        <form name="add_name" id="add_name" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="id" value="01">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- el type deberia ser submit en el boton de envio -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### PHP

```
// se asume conexion en $conn interfaz MySQLi
include 'include/conexion.php';
// Comprobamos  si se envio el form
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) AND isset($_POST['id']) )
{
    // comprobamos que haya almenos un elemento name
    if(count($_POST["name"]) > 0)
    {
        // creamos la consulta
        $sql = "INSERT INTO observacion (id,motivo) VALUES( ?, ? );";
        // preparamos la consulta
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // asignamos id
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        // recorremos $_POST['name']
        foreach ($_POST['name'] as $motivo)
        {
          //comprobamos que se escribio algo
            if(trim($motivo) != '')
            {
              // si se escribio ejecutamos la co
              $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $motivo);
              $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
        ?> 
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Observacion Ingresada!</strong> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Please Enter Name";
    }
}
```

---

---

Dejo el código en un archivo.php para probarlo, solo configurar los datos de la base de datos, se asume una tabla llamada ´observación´ con almenos las columnas ´id´ y ´motivo´ :

### Ejemplo_completo.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var i=1;
          $('#add').click(function(){
               i++;
               $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
          });
          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
               var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
               $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
          });  
     });
     </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Este input deberia estar dentro del form -->
    <!-- <input type="text" name="id" value="01"> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- En el form falta el action y el method -->
        <form name="add_name" id="add_name" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="id" value="01">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- el type deberia ser submit en el boton de envio -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'base_datos') or die("Error con la base de datos.");
/* Comprueba la conexión */
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit;
}

// se asume conexion en $conn interfaz MySQLi
//include 'include/conexion.php';
// Comprobamos  si se envio el form
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) AND isset($_POST['id']) )
{
    // comprobamos que haya almenos un elemento name
    if(count($_POST["name"]) > 0)
    {
        // creamos la consulta
        $sql = "INSERT INTO observacion (id, motivo) VALUES( ?, ? );";
        // preparamos la consulta
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // asignamos id
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        // recorremos $_POST['name']
        foreach ($_POST['name'] as $motivo)
        {
          //comprobamos que se escribio algo
            if(trim($motivo) != '')
            {
              // si se escribio ejecutamos la co
              $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $motivo);
              $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
        ?> 
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Observacion Ingresada!</strong> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Please Enter Name";
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si luego tengo un poco de tiempo te añado un ejemplo del código con sentencias preparadas.

Comment: te lo agradecería mucho saludos!!

Comment: Igual, al agregar mas texbox sigue solo agregando el primer textbox.

Comment: Puede ser que en el 
<input type="text" name="id" value="01">
yo la Id del trabajador la hago de esta forma.
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php
        echo $row['id']; ?>">

Comment: Si se imprime el id correctamente no deberia haber problema. Pero si que debe de estar el `input` dentro del `form`, en tu código lo ponias fuera. @MoteCL

Comment: Ahora si funciona.
Muchas gracias te lo agradezco mucho!!!@Xerif estoy haciendo mi practica profesional y en la oficina mucho lo saben programación. Muy agradecido

Comment: Te puse igualmente el ejemplo completo, igualmente me di cuenta que me equivoque en el nombre de la tabla. Me alegra que te haya servido, un saludo y gracias por tus puntos. @MoteCL

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar he iterado por cada índice de `$_POST["name"]` en vez de hacer un bucle `for`, pero creo que lo más importante es que he cambiado la siguiente línea:

```
/* Mal */
if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))
/* Bien (nótese el cierre de paréntesis) */
if(trim($_POST["name"][$i]) != '')
```

También he controlado cualquier error que pueda generar la consulta, ya que en caso de que tengas problemas por clave duplicada, error de sintaxis, etc, no te enterarías de ninguna manera.

Resultado:

```
<?php
include 'include/conexion.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /* Iteramos por cada índice */
    foreach ($_POST["name"] as $i => $nombre) {
        /* Cuidado con los paréntesis de aquí */
        if (trim($nombre) !== '') {
            $sql = "
                INSERT INTO observacion (
                    id,
                    motivo
                ) VALUES(
                    '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id'][$i]) . "',
                    '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nombre) . "'
                )
            ";
            /* Comprobamos si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente */
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) === false) {
                die(mysqli_error($conn));
            }
        }
    }
?>        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>Observacion Ingresada!</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    } else {
        echo "Please Enter Name";
    }
}
```

Comment: Te añadí un comentario en el trim, a simple vista no me di cuenta de que habías cambiado! ; )

Comment: Gracias, ayer tuve una tarde ocupada y no pude revisar ninguna de mis respuestas. Voy a cambiar el formato de comentario para que aparezca en gris. Y ya he visto que tu respuesta era la correcta, me da lástima no haber tenido tiempo para poder revisar todo antes :) te dejo mi +1 en tu respuesta. También me da rabia porque con mi código hubiera recibido un error SQL que le hubiera explicado el problema que tenía en la consulta x(